# TypeScript compiler for Python

Tags: library, javascript, python, compiler

I need a library capable of compiling TypeScript to JS for Python.

- Platform: Python 2.7.x.
- If the library depends on an external executable, the SO is Ubuntu 14.04 or upper. Otherwise, SO doesn't matter.
- Expected features (at least one of them):

  - Given a TypeScript filename, generate compiled JS.
  - Given a TypeScript chunk (string), generate compiled JS chunk (string).
- Package/repository actively maintained.

Comment: Your question and title do not match: are you looking for a compiler or a parser? I think you would be best for compiling to use a regular typescript compiler and call this from Python

Comment: For the sake of typescript usage as of today, the distinction is irrelevant. But yes, i will update the question now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this https://github.com/amol-/dukpy which is a combo of Python and C and offers limited TypeScript compilation capabilities.

In general you might be better off using a native TypeScript compiler and call it from Python instead

Comment: It's also possible to compile TypeScript to JavaScript, and then translate it into Python using a [JavaScript-to-Python compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346584/conversion-from-javascript-to-python-code) such as js2py.